# ServiceStack ORMLite - Invalid Column Name EntityId

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack ORMLite for the first time and I get an error "Invalid Column Name 'EntityId'" when executing the following command from my DataRepositoryBase< T> base class:

```
public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = CreateDbConnection())
        {
            return db.Where<T>(e => e.EntityId == id).SingleOrDefault(); //ERROR HERE                     
        }
    }
```

All of my classes implement the following Interface:

```
public interface IIdentifiableEntity
{
    int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

On my class that I have the following property:

```
[XmlIgnore]
    [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Ignore]
    public int EntityId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myPrimaryKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.myPrimaryKey = value;
        }
    }
```

The EntityId property is not an actual field in the database but I use that so that I can always reference the primary key of any of my classes by calling EntityId.

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you are trying to filter on a column that does not exist in your database. Instead of `e.EntityId == id` try `e.myPrimaryKey == id`. You could also use the `Alias("DbFieldName")]` attribute to _rename_ your primary key field to always be EntityId.